# Golang Скачивание архива bz2 и распаковка на лету

Tags: golang, streaming, bz2

Есть задача - скачать базу просроченных паспортов и положить в БД (как вариант). Архив весит примерно 410mb.

Вариант первый - сначала скачать потом читать и полученные номера паспортов раскладывать по диапазонам. Работает, реализовано в функции

> readFile

Вариант второй - скачивать порциями, и сразу рассортировывать. Не работает

> DownloadFile

читаю чанками, и пишу в канал, но никак не могу понять почему не получается распаковывать данные. Вроде те же **slice byte**

Может ли кто нибудь дать наводку куда копать?

```
func decompress(chunkIn chan io.Reader, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    out := make(chan int64)
    defer close(out)
    defer wg.Done()
    wg.Add(1)
    go rangeCombine(out, wg)
    for chunk := range chunkIn{
        br := bufio.NewReader(chunk)
        cr := bzip2.NewReader(br)
        d := bufio.NewReader(cr)
        s := bufio.NewScanner(d)
        line := make([]byte, 30)
        for s.Scan() {
             line = []byte(strings.Replace(string(s.Bytes()), ",", "", 1))
             number, err := strconv.Atoi(string(line))
             out <- int64(number) // example 4100123123
        }
    }
}

func readFile(filePath string) {
    var file io.Reader
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    chunk := make([]byte, 1024 * 1024 * ChunkSize)
    chunkOut := make(chan io.Reader)
    wg.Add(1)
    go decompress(chunkOut, wg)
    for {
        n, err := file.Read(chunk)
        chunkOut <- bytes.NewReader(chunk)
        chunk = []byte{}
    }
    close(chunkOut)
    wg.Wait()
}



func DownloadFile(url string) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    chunk := make([]byte, 1024 * 1024 * ChunkSize)
    chunkOut := make(chan io.Reader)
    wg.Add(1)
    go decompress(chunkOut, wg)

    for {
        _, err := resp.Body.Read(chunk)
        chunkOut <- bytes.NewReader(chunk)
        //chunk = []byte{}
    }
    close(chunkOut)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. Данные приходили маленькими кусочками, поэтому пришлось их накапливать. Вот работающая реализация

```
func DownloadFilesNew(url string) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    chunk := make([]byte, ChunkSize)
    chunkData := make([]byte, 0, ChunkSize)
    chunkOut := make(chan io.Reader)
    wg.Add(1)
    go decompress(chunkOut, wg)

    remain := 0
    for {
        i++
        remain = 0
        n, err := resp.Body.Read(chunk)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if len(chunkData) + n > ChunkSize {
            remain = (len(chunkData) + n) - ChunkSize
        }

        chunkData = append(chunkData, chunk[:n-remain]...)
        if len(chunkData) == ChunkSize {
            chunkOut <- bytes.NewReader(chunkData)
            chunkData = chunk[n-remain:n]
        }
        chunk = make([]byte, ChunkSize)
    }

    close(chunkOut)
    wg.Wait()
}
```